# Passing parameters in multiple screen in flutter app using php,mysql

Tags: php, flutter, dart

Login page code

```
import 'package:carousel/UserDataDb.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:carousel/PortalPage.dart';


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State {

  bool visible = false ;
  // Getting value from TextField widget.
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future userLogin() async{

    // Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      visible = true ;
    });
    // Getting value from Controller
    String email = emailController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'http://helloflutter.com/test/login_user.php';
 // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'email': email, 'password' : password};
   // print(data['password']);
    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var dv_values=message.split('#');

    UserDataDb user=new UserDataDb(dv_values[1],dv_values[2],dv_values[3],dv_values[4]);

    // If the Response Message is Matched.
    if(dv_values[0]== 'gotit')
    {

      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });


      // Navigate to Profile Screen & Sending Email to Next Screen.
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PortalPage(user:user))
     );
    }else{

      // If Email or Password did not Matched.
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });
     // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );}

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar:  new AppBar(
          backgroundColor:Colors.white ,
          title:  new Center(child: new Text("SBOATWS", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),)),

        ),
        body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color.fromRGBO(255, 65, 108, 1.0),
                      Color.fromRGBO(255, 75, 73, 1.0)
                    ] )
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Text('User Login Form',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21))),

                  Divider(),

                  Container(
                      width: 280,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        autocorrect: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your User Id Here'),
                      )
                  ),

                  Container(
                      width: 280,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: passwordController,
                        autocorrect: true,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Password Here'),
                      )
                  ),

                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: userLogin,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                    child: Text('Login'),
                  ),


                  Visibility(
                      visible: visible,
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                      )
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

**Portal page code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel/ProductsCarousel.dart';
import 'package:carousel/MyProfile.dart';
import 'package:carousel/LoginPage.dart';
import 'package:carousel/MyInvestment.dart';

import 'UserDataDb.dart';

class PortalPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final UserDataDb user;
  PortalPage({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PortalPageState createState() => _PortalPageState();
}

class _PortalPageState extends State<PortalPage> {
 // final String email;
  Offset _offset=Offset(0,0);
  GlobalKey _globalKey=GlobalKey();
  List<double> limits=[];
  bool ismenuopen=false;



  @override
  void initState() {
    limits=[0,0,0,0,0,0];

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(getposition);
    super.initState();
  }

    getposition(duration)
    {
    RenderBox rb=_globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  final position=  rb.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    double start=position.dy-20;
    double constLimit=position.dy+rb.size.height-20;
    double step=(constLimit-start)/6;
    limits=[];
      for(double x=start;x<=constLimit;x=x+step)
        {
          limits.add(x);
        }
      setState(() {
        limits=limits;
      });
    }

    getfontsize(int indexbutton)
    {
      double size=(_offset.dy>limits[indexbutton] && _offset.dy<limits[indexbutton+1])?25:20;
      return size;
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //AssetImage useravatar = AssetImage('assets/bl.jpg');
    Size mediaQuery=MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double sidebarwidth=mediaQuery.width * 0.65;
    double sidebarmenuheight=mediaQuery.height/2;
    var pic=widget.user.propic;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(255, 65, 108, 1.0),
                Color.fromRGBO(255, 75, 73, 1.0)
              ] )
          ),
          width: mediaQuery.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
              //RathiN--bring profile image
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                     
                      Text('Welcome to Home page',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),)

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedPositioned(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                left: ismenuopen?0:-sidebarwidth+20,
                top: 0,
                curve: Curves.elasticOut,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: sidebarwidth,
                  child:GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (details){
                            if(details.localPosition.dx<=sidebarwidth)
                              {
                                setState(() {
                                  _offset=details.localPosition;
                                });
                              }
                            if(details.localPosition.dx>sidebarwidth+20 && details.delta.distanceSquared>2)
                              setState(() {
                                ismenuopen=true;
                              });

                    },
                    onPanEnd: (details){
                      _offset=Offset(0,0);
                    },
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CustomPaint(
                        size: Size(sidebarwidth,mediaQuery.height),
                        painter:RathinPainter(offset: _offset) ,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: mediaQuery.height,
                        width: sidebarwidth,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: mediaQuery.height*0.25,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(pic),
                                      radius: 50.0,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text( widget.user.name.toString(),style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),),
                                    Text( " ( "+widget.user.job.toString()+" )",style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.redAccent,fontSize: 10.0),)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                            ),
                            Divider(thickness: 1,),
                            Container(
                              key: _globalKey,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: sidebarmenuheight,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  MyButton(
                                    text:"Profile",
                                    iconData:Icons.person,
                                    textSize:getfontsize(0),
                                    height:(sidebarmenuheight)/5,
                                  ),
                                  MyButton(
                                    text:"Portfolio",
                                    iconData:Icons.redeem,
                                    textSize:getfontsize(1),
                                    height:(sidebarmenuheight)/5,
                                  ),
                                  MyButton(
                                    text:"Attendance",
                                    iconData:Icons.done_all,
                                    textSize:getfontsize(2),
                                    height:(sidebarmenuheight)/5,
                                  ),
                                  MyButton(
                                    text:"Applications",
                                    iconData:Icons.file_download,

                                    textSize:getfontsize(3),
                                    height:(sidebarmenuheight)/5,
                                  ),

                                  MyButton(
                                    text:"Logout",
                                    iconData:Icons.exit_to_app,
                                    textSize:getfontsize(4),
                                    height:(sidebarmenuheight)/5,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],

                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedPositioned
                        (
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              right: (ismenuopen)?10:sidebarwidth,
                              bottom: 30,
                             child: IconButton(
                               enableFeedback: true,
                               icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_backspace,color: Colors.redAccent,size: 30,),
                               onPressed: (){
                                 this.setState(() {
                                   ismenuopen=false;
                                 });
                               },
                             ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class RathinPainter extends CustomPainter{
  final Offset offset;

  RathinPainter({this.offset});

  double getControlPointEx(double width){
    if(offset.dx==0){
      return width;
    }else{
      return offset.dx>width?offset.dx:width+75;
    }

  }
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint p=Paint()..color=Colors.white..style= PaintingStyle.fill;
    Path path=Path();
    path.moveTo(-size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(getControlPointEx(size.width), offset.dy, size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(-size.width, size.height);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, p);
    

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
   return true;
  }
 
}


class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData iconData;
  final double textSize;
  final double height;

  MyButton(
      {
        this.text,
        this.iconData,
        this.textSize,
        this.height,
    }
      );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      height: height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            iconData,
            color: Colors.black45,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,fontSize: textSize),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onPressed: (){
        if(this.text=="Applications") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductsCarousel()),
          );
        }else  if(this.text=="Profile") {

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyProfile()),
          );
        }//else if end
        else  if(this.text=="Portfolio") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyInvestment()),
          );
        }//else if end
        else  if(this.text=="Logout") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
          );
        }//else if end
       // print( this.text);
        },
    );
  }
}
```

**Profile page code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:carousel/PortalPage.dart';

import 'UserDataDb.dart';

class MyProfile extends StatelessWidget {



  var src="https://cdn.dnaindia.com/sites/default/files/styles/full/public/2018/08/21/721062-triptidimri-082218.jpg";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color.fromRGBO(255, 65, 108, 1.0),
                      Color.fromRGBO(255, 75, 73, 1.0)
                    ] )
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 350.0,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(src),
                      radius: 50.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text("Dummy",
                    style:TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Card(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0,vertical: 10.0),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 8.0,

                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0,vertical: 10.0),
                          child: Row(

                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                Text("ID",
                                style:TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(199, 0, 57 , 0.9),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                ),
                                  Text("Test",
                                    style:TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(144, 12, 63,1),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Deposit",
                                    style:TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(199, 0, 57 , 0.9),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text("77000",
                                    style:TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(144, 12, 63,1),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Outstanding",
                                    style:TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(199, 0, 57 , 0.9),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text("89000",
                                    style:TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(144, 12, 63,1),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],


                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Second Part
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0,horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
               // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("About",
                    style:TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Color.fromRGBO(144, 12, 63,1),fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,

                  ),
                  Text("Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,

          ),
          Container(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.65,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PortalPage()),
                );
              },
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)
              ),
              elevation: 0.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Ink(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Color.fromRGBO(255, 65, 108, 1.0),
                          Color.fromRGBO(255, 75, 73, 1.0)
                        ] ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),

                ),
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: 300.0,
                    minHeight: 30.0,
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Back",
                    style:TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,fontFamily: "Verdaba",color:Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ) ,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I have passed the data of user's which is collected using mysql php http to second page(screen2) and able to display that. but from page2(Portal page) , I am unable to send the data to page(3). When I return from page 3  (Profile page) to page 2(Portal page)  then I am getting an error as---The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: findRenderObject()**

---

Please anyone can guide me how to pass & travel the data around multiple pages in flutter dart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a state management solution. Get started [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I did that.Thanks